# Выделение слов автора посередине мысленной речи только запятыми: что это за правило?

Tags: запятые, тире, прямая-речь, оформление-текста, несобственно-прямая-речь

Как известно, слова автора, стоящие посередине прямой речи, отделяются от неё с двух сторон запятой и тире (см. [здесь](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_192)), а вся реплика либо заключается в кавычки (например, при мысленной речи), либо начинается с тире (в диалоге). Вот пример.

- «Если дать всем, ― **подумал он**, ― это влетит в копеечку». [Коллекция анекдотов: Ходжа Насреддин (1950-2000)]

Однако в литературе встречается выделение авторских слов в мысленной речи при помощи ТОЛЬКО ЗАПЯТЫХ (никаких вам кавычек для мыслей и тире с запятыми). Это что, допустимая форма несобственно-прямой речи? А где это правило прописано? Вот несколько примеров для наглядности.

1. По меньшей мере трое, **мысленно поправил себя Николай**, потому что Тамара приезжала в райцентр три раза с разными группами немцев, и в каждой из этих групп Саприн безошибочно вычленял одного, который считал, что имеет на Тамару кое-какие права. [Александра Маринина. За все надо платить (1995)]
2. Ах, чтоб тебе пропасть, дураку, **мысленно выругался Тумаш**. [Василь Быков. Болото (2001)]
3. Господи, Боже ты мой, вот уж точно, распалась связь времён, **подумал он**, французского вина подайте-ка арестованному… [Юрий Давыдов. Синие тюльпаны (1988-1989)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (06.08.2023)**

"Грамота.ру" не возражает (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310754)):

> Правил оформления несобственно-прямой речи в справочниках по русской пунктуации и редактированию текста не приводится. Очевидно, здесь стоит ориентироваться на существующую речевую практику.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что в таких случаях авторские ремарки приравниваются к обособленным оборотам, близким по смыслу к выражению "по словам такого-то", а потому выделяются запятыми по общему правилу.